# Make Storyboard view more realistic

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard

This is how my xcode shows the storyboard:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/O7dHdYG.png]

How can I make xcode show a more realistic storyboard of my app? For example, like [this](http://blog.mengto.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Intro.png):

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you mean? What do you mean by a more realistic storyboard? Also, what map? Do you mean you want the image views to show the images? Lease add more detail to the question. Thanks

Comment: Well, I want it to show how my app will actually look like. Not just what objects I've added to the storyboard. Something like this: http://blog.mengto.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Intro.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, first off.

That website you linked to is a mock up of an app using image views. It isn't what a storyboard looks like.

The best approach to get your storyboard looking more real is to fill it with dummy data. If you have a UIImageView that is supposed to show someone's avatar then get a picture of someone and put it into that image view. It won't be the real avatar but it will show you what it's like.

If you have labels that show numbers if followers then put actual numbers (not Xs) in there.

The thing to remember though is that the storyboard is not your app. Just like code that you write doesn't look like code when you run the app. The story board is just a way of defining interface objects and layouts.

But yeah, that website is just a mockup, it isn't a real storyboard. Look at the class of all the VCs. They are all just ViewController.